# Peoplesoft CreateRowset with related display record

Tags: record, peoplesoft, rowset, peoplesoft-app-engine

According to the [Peoplebook here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57990_01/pt853pbh2/eng/pt/tpcl/langref_PeopleCodeBuilt-inFunctionsandLanguageConstructs-073e6a.html#uf64191c5-36b5-422f-a402-53be7ee1e6a0), CreateRowset function has the parameters {FIELD.fieldname, RECORD.recname} which is used to specify the related display record.

I had tried to use it like the following (just for example):

```
&rs1 = CreateRowset(Record.User, Field.UserId, Record.UserName);
&rs1.Fill();

For &k = 1 To &rs1.ActiveRowCount
MessageBox(0, "", 999999, 99999, &rs1(&k).UserName.Name.Value);
End-for;
```

(Record.User contains only UserId(key), Password.
Record.UserName contains UserId(key), Name.)

I cannot get the Value of UserName.Name, do I misunderstand the usage of this parameter?

Comment: 1) Is this the actual code? I don't have a "User" record in my installation. 2) I've never done it with a related display record. Is there a reason you can't use the other syntax with just a record name?

Comment: 1. Sorry, this is only the idea and not the actual code. The problem I want to ask is that I cannot get any values of any fields from the related display record by using CreateRowset with the parameters {FIELD.fieldname, RECORD.recname}

Comment: 2. In fact the original code is e.g. &rs1 = CreateRowset(record.A), and now I have to include some related values into this rowset at the same level from another record (e.g record.B) which is related to the primary record (record.A) by key. I may create a record view from record.A and B to replace the record.A, but many codes under this &rs1 will be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill is the problem. From the [doco](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57990_01/pt853pbh2/eng/pt/tpcr/langref_RowsetClassMethods-c07c55.html#u6c5a2697-5a93-4547-a5e7-9fe4c3b7f8c2):

> Note: Fill reads only the primary database record. It does not read
>   any related records, nor any subordinate rowset records.

Having said that, it is the only way I know to bulk-populate a standalone rowset from the database, so I can't easily see a use for the field in the rowset.

Simplest solution is just to create a view, but that gets old very soon if you have to do it a lot. Alternative is to just loop through the rowset yourself loading the related fields. Something like:

```
For &k = 1 To &rs1.ActiveRowCount
  &rs1(&k).UserName.UserId.value = &rs1(&k).User.UserId.value;
  &rs1(&k).UserName.SelectByKey();
End-for;
```